# Javascript Screen Width/Media Query If Statement That Returns an Alert Box if True

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, media-queries, alert

I am *very* new to Javascript and web development as a whole and I'm quite stuck with an If Statement here. The objective of this code is to read if the screen width (or media query) is below 450px, and if so display an alert box - I'm only needing this to work on one page at the moment.

The HTML:

```
either

<body onload="fullQuote()">

-or- (I'm not sure if the second actually works)

<script>window.onload = fullQuote()</script>
```

The JavaScript:

```
function fullQuote() {
var mediaQuery = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 450px)");
if (mediaQuery.matches) {
    alert("Test");
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find an answer as to whats wrong with this code anywhere, but I have tried different methods of finding out the screen size like

```
if (screen.width <= 450) {
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 450) {
```

and also a boolean within the if parentheses:

```
if (mediaQuery.matches == true) {
```

among some other ways around this now lost to memory which, of course, shared the same failed results.

Any help to where I am going wrong this matter would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks,

Will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## window.onload

this will not work because you are invoking the function when setting the `window.onload` property. you need to write it like this.

```
<script>window.onload = fullQuote</script>
```

this way you are setting `window.onload` to equal a function, not the return of the invoked function.

## Getting screen width

the ideal way to get the screen width is to use `window.innerWidth`

```
if(window.innerWidth < 451) //...
```

## Extra: Detect resize

if you want to detect changes, you can add a listener on window resize as such.

```
document.addEventListener('resize', fullQuote);
```

however i do not recommend using alert while using even listeners as alerts are sync operations, which might cause some problems or jank.